# laying out month names in two columns using css

Tags: html, css, css-float

what HTML and CSS would you use to layout the names of the months in two columns like:

```
january july
feb     aug
mar     sep
apr     oct
may     nov
jun     dec
```

month names are coming from an array and html is dynamically generated for i18n purposes.

If it was:

```
january february
mar     apr
 ...
```

I would just put them in a DIV, all with double the width of a single month + some space and float them. but ordering them as stated seems more complicated...

Must i introduce two additional DIVs for the columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the HTML is generated, you could do something like this ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PcDdf/)):

```
<div style="width: 100px">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun',
                      'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'];
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            document.write('<div style="width: 50px;float: left">' + months[i] + '</div>');
            document.write('<div style="width: 50px;float: left">' + months[i + 6] + '</div>');
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a single div and assign the following CSS

```
column-count: 2;
-moz-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
```

This creates 2 columns that are filled with the data given.

Further reading: [column-count@MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/column-count) and [multi column layouts @caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn)

Comment: I don't believe that any version of IE currently supports CSS3 columns yet.

Comment: IE10 will. For IE9 and below, polyfills exist, as with jQuery: http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/ . Otherwise you're back to separating the 12 months in 2 LISTS of months

Answer (score 1):

You can try to generate this html:

```
<div style="width: 200px; float: left">
  <p>MONTH FROM 1 TO 6</p>
</div>
<div style="width: 200px; float: left">
  <p>MONTH FROM 7 TO 12</p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Of course you can move the styles definition to a CSS stylesheet